# Ordering and binding in for loop r

Tags: r, for-loop, mean

I want my for loop to store data in rows, based on the correct order as specified in the for loop, but somehow the data is bound randomly in a new dataframe.

Background information:

- I have a dataframe with data from the FMCG industry, amongst this are the prices for products.
- My dataframe consists of the top 3 brands of 55 different product categories
- In my econometric (marketing) model I also accommodate for competition, so what I do is calculating average prices of the competition of Brand A, B and C based on conditions.
- When I run the loop for one category, say category 5 (from my total dataset), I get the right averages in order and stack these, so I can bind them to my main dataframe. This main dataframe has all the brands listed from top to bottom, for every category, for every week.
- THE PROBLEM: when I run the for loop, it does calculate the averages, but the final stacked dataframe to bind shuffled all the values so that they are not in order anymore.
- So, I need to find a command that keeps my calculated averages in order (so average of competition Category 5 Brand A week 1 as the first row and average of Category 550 Brand C week 208 as last), as happens when I do it for one category, but not in the for loop.

The code:

```
##for loop for all competitor average prices accross all categories
    for(X in c("5", "24", "32", "43", "49", "56", "63", "81", "94", "96", "102", "105", "115", "122", "129", "133", "145", "154", "180", "189", "201", "210", "219", "226", "231", "245", "264", "277", "280", "301", "313", "335", "346", "361", "397", "409", "410", "411", "413", "437", "443", "480", "488", "493", "500", "516", "526", "533", "535", "536", "542", "543", "549", "550")){
  PriceX <- read.table(paste0("/Users/censored",X,".csv"), header=TRUE, sep=",")
  PriceX <- transpose(PriceX)
  PriceX <- PriceX[-c(1), ] #deleting the first column of df, contains brand names
  PriceX <- transpose(PriceX)
  PriceX <- sapply(PriceX, as.numeric)
  PriceX <- data.frame(PriceX)
  CompPriceXa <- PriceX[-c(1:2), ] #delete first and second row, contains totals and Brand A
  CompPriceXa <- CompPriceXa %>%  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(. == 0, NA, .))) #Make all zeros NA, otherwise the means are calculated over rows. 
  CompPriceXa <- colMeans(CompPriceXa, na.rm=T) #calculate the mean of competitor prices when Brand A is focal brand
  CompPriceXa <- as.matrix(CompPriceXa)
  CompPriceXb <- PriceX[-c(1, 3), ]
   CompPriceXb <- CompPriceXb %>%  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(. == 0, NA, .)))
  CompPriceXb <- colMeans(CompPriceXb, na.rm=T)
  CompPriceXb <- as.matrix(CompPriceXb)
  CompPriceXc <- PriceX[-c(1, 4), ]
  CompPriceXc <- CompPriceXc %>%  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(. == 0, NA, .)))
  CompPriceXc <- colMeans(CompPriceXc, na.rm=T)
  CompPriceXc <- as.matrix(CompPriceXc)
  StackedCompPrice <- rbind(CompPriceXa, CompPriceXb, CompPriceXc) #stack the average competitor prices of Brand A, B and C. 
  StackedCompPrice <- as.data.frame(StackedCompPrice)
  ALLStackedCompPrice <- rbind(StackedCompPrice, ALLStackedCompPrice)}

ALLStackedCompPrice <- StackedCompPrice[NULL,] #first run the for loop, then run this command outside loop to create empty df, then run the forloop again and it will be filled with all the values from all categories
```

Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: can you provide a sample of the data after it gets read in? There seems to be some unnecessary steps here. Also, you don't want this in a for loop. You want to turn this into a function, and then maybe lapply against a vector or list of numbers, and then transform the list you get back into an ordered dataframe. but I'm not sure without looking at the data. try using `dput(head(PriceX, 30))` after you read in the first.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if I should do this in a for loop as well. I did it with two other variables like this and it worked perfectly. I'm not that experienced in R so other ways could solve the issue too. I just need to calculate competitor averages for every week (208 in total) and bind these values to the main dataframe. I'll  put an illustration of my df so far in an answer below.

Comment: You're doing a lot of extra work here. Some sample data would help (scrubbed for confidentiality is fine). It looks like Row 1 is totals? The other rows I'm not fully understanding. Are there more rows than just 1:4? I notice you are removing either 2 or 3 or 4 and then doing the math on the rest, but am not sure why.

Comment: Here is the download of the csv file of category 5 so you can look into it: https://files.fm/u/38ssqqzz. Column 1 is a brand indicator, which I do not need. Row 1 is indeed totals, which I don't need as well. Then row 2 is Brand A, row 3 Brand B and row 4 is Brand C. But every category has a different amount of brands. The average is calculated over all the other brands (=rows) in the column. And this is then done 208 times, one average for every week. In order to get a right mean, I make the 0 as NA, so it calculates the mean over the true values. I use the for loop since it are 55 categries

Comment: I can't download that when I don't know whats behind it - I'm on a work computer. `dput(head(df, 30))` should be enough to show us. It will print out the structure into your R console, and then you just copy and past the structure output and add it to your question at the bottom.

Comment: Will do, but my df contains 208 columns, any idea how to limit that too?

Comment: yeah `dput(df[1:30,1:20])` that will give thirty rows and twenty columns

Comment: Did so! Thanks, the copying went not that well but I hope you can make sense of it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole issue is solved! It was something very simple... just reversing the for loop, so category '550' as first and '5' as last and there you go. The for loop is maybe a bit big and could be done quicker, but as long as it works it is fine, haha. Thanks for your quick responses and help!

Answer (score 0):

If you nest another for loop, and put that for loop's assigner inside the dataframe indices you want to modify that should solve your problem. Obviously without data this answer is just guidance rather than concrete code...

```
    ##for loop for all competitor average prices accross all categories
        for(X in c("5", "24", "32", "43", "49", "56", "63", "81", "94", "96", "102", "105", "115", "122", "129", "133", "145", "154", "180", "189", "201", "210", "219", "226", "231", "245", "264", "277", "280", "301", "313", "335", "346", "361", "397", "409", "410", "411", "413", "437", "443", "480", "488", "493", "500", "516", "526", "533", "535", "536", "542", "543", "549", "550")){
      PriceX <- read.table(paste0("/Users/censored",X,".csv"), header=TRUE, sep=",")
      PriceX <- transpose(PriceX)
      PriceX <- PriceX[-c(1), ] #deleting the first column of df, contains brand names
      PriceX <- transpose(PriceX)
      PriceX <- sapply(PriceX, as.numeric)
      PriceX <- data.frame(PriceX)
      CompPriceXa <- PriceX[-c(1:2), ] #delete first and second row, contains totals and Brand A
      CompPriceXa <- CompPriceXa %>%  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(. == 0, NA, .))) #Make all zeros NA, otherwise the means are calculated over rows. 
      CompPriceXa <- colMeans(CompPriceXa, na.rm=T) #calculate the mean of competitor prices when Brand A is focal brand
      CompPriceXa <- as.matrix(CompPriceXa)
      CompPriceXb <- PriceX[-c(1, 3), ]
       CompPriceXb <- CompPriceXb %>%  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(. == 0, NA, .)))
      CompPriceXb <- colMeans(CompPriceXb, na.rm=T)
      CompPriceXb <- as.matrix(CompPriceXb)
      CompPriceXc <- PriceX[-c(1, 4), ]
      CompPriceXc <- CompPriceXc %>%  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(. == 0, NA, .)))
      CompPriceXc <- colMeans(CompPriceXc, na.rm=T)
      CompPriceXc <- as.matrix(CompPriceXc)
      StackedCompPrice <- rbind(CompPriceXa, CompPriceXb, CompPriceXc) #stack the average competitor prices of Brand A, B and C. 
      StackedCompPrice <- as.data.frame(StackedCompPrice)
for(i in 1:5{
      ALLStackedCompPrice[,i]<- rbind(StackedCompPrice, ALLStackedCompPrice)
}}

    ALLStackedCompPrice <- StackedCompPrice[NULL,] #first run the for loop, then run this command outside loop to create empty df, then run the forloop again and it will be filled with all the values from all categories
```

Comment: Tried to run this, but somehow there are unmatched brackets so it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the links, I have made screenshots of my dataframes to give you an illustration of my data.

[Main dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go3Jb.png)

[Dataset for calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJHLf.png)

[Averages as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roelf.png)

Answer (score 0):

This will give an impression of the dataset I do the calculations on:

X Var1 Var2Var3 Var4

1-1 6.584001 6.618493   6.669796 6.14605

2-1 6.316876 6.299771 6.264874 5.531244

3-1
3.914301
3.953827
3.955841
3.640814

4-1
3.629302
3.655962
3.657091
3.525953

5-1
4.801913
4.791146
4.819135
4.888309